# How can I reduce Bootstrap column widths to the size of a specific button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Not really sure how to set the title. My problem is obvious visually.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21442/

```
  <div class="row">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="From">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="To">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="29/11/2015">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="Return">
    <select class="col-xs-2">
      <option>1 Passenger</option>
      <option>2 Passengers</option>
      <option>3 Passengers</option>
      <option>4 Passengers</option>
      <option>5 Passengers</option>
      <option>6 Passengers</option>
    </select>
    <button class="col-xs-2" id="search-btn">S</button>
  </div>
```

The search button have to be in certain width, so there is unfilled space at the right, how can I fill it till the end? the wrapper has certain fixed width.

Comment: Remove the width given in #search-btn button css

Comment: @MukeshRam No i want the button to be that size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```
input,
select {
  height: 40px;
  flex:1;
}

#search-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhoygc5v/)

```css
 body {
   margin: 10px;
 }
 .container {
   width: 500px;
   background: #333;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 input,
 select {
   height: 40px;
   flex: 1;
 }
 #search-btn {
   width: 50px;
   height: 40px;
 }
 .row {
   margin: 0;
   display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="From">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="To">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="29/11/2015">
    <input class="col-xs-2" type="" name="" placeholder="Return">
    <select class="col-xs-2">
      <option>1 Passenger</option>
      <option>2 Passengers</option>
      <option>3 Passengers</option>
      <option>4 Passengers</option>
      <option>5 Passengers</option>
      <option>6 Passengers</option>
    </select>
    <button class="col-xs-2" id="search-btn">S</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you have to look outside the Bootstrap scope here. Why? Bootstrap has a scope of 12, which cannot be divided by 5. Why 5 you think? Well, youhave a fixed width on the button, so you now have 5 items remaining that have to fill up the space. So you have to think a bit out of the box.

I have used the calc function within CSS to calculate the space of your container, minus the 50px. That will be the 100%, then you fill it with the 5 items in equal lenght (20%).

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21451/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="filler">
        <input class="fifth" type="" name="" placeholder="From">
        <input class="fifth" type="" name="" placeholder="To">
        <input class="fifth" type="" name="" placeholder="29/11/2015">
        <input class="fifth" type="" name="" placeholder="Return">
        <select class="fifth">
          <option>1 Passenger</option>
          <option>2 Passengers</option>
          <option>3 Passengers</option>
          <option>4 Passengers</option>
          <option>5 Passengers</option>
      <option>6 Passengers</option>
    </select>
    </div>   
    <button class="" id="search-btn">S</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your new CSS.

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/    
/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.filler {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px); 
}

.fifth {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 20%;
}


input,
select {
  height: 40px;
}

#search-btn {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 40px;

}

.row {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just remove the width in your css, the search-btn id must be like this:

```
#search-btn {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: According to the jsfiddle, the OP wants the button to be a fixed width of 50px. Removing the width would decrease the width to 39px, which is not what she wants.

Answer (score -3):

In the search you have given ID="#search-btn"

In that you have mention the style

`#search-btn {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}`

remove the Width in it.